# Aggregation of different actions

Tags: action, facebook-opengraph

In my application I'd like to send different actions:

- read article
- watch video
- view gallery

How can I aggregate all these actions? I can get actions by type of an action:
"namespace:action_type" (graph API). How can I get all actions done by a user?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the Activity Plugin, and specify the actions param with a CSV list of all the actions you'd like it to show - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity2/. This would them show the actions of those types performed by the viewing users friends on your domain.

```
actions="news.reads,namespace:action1,namespace:action2"
```

Its not possible to make a single API call to get all the actions by the user, or all the actions by the user in your app - you must make one call per action type. You can use the Batch API to make multiple calls at once: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/